# Basic question about automorphic representations

Tags: complex-analysis, group-theory, functional-analysis, representation-theory, automorphic-forms

I'm reading Gelfand/Graev/Pyatetskii-Shapiro's book *Representation Theory and Automorphic Functions*. On page 20, the setting is:

Let $G$ be a locally compact topological group, $\Gamma\le G$ a discrete subgroup (assumed to be cocompact).

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space (which I assume they want to be over $\mathbb{C}$), and $\chi : \Gamma\rightarrow V$ a unitary representation of $\Gamma$ (so I guess they want $V$ to be equipped with an inner product). Let $H(\chi)$ denote the Hilbert space of measurable functions $f : G\rightarrow V$ satisfying:

1. $f(\gamma g) = \chi(\gamma)f(g)$ for all $\gamma\in\Gamma,g\in G$.
2. $(f,f) := \int_{\Gamma\backslash G}[f,f]dx < \infty$, where $[f,f]$ denotes the inner product of $V$.

Here, I think they really want the integral to be over a fundamental domain, and I think the choice of fundamental domain doesn't matter because $\chi$ is unitary.

For $g\in G$, they define the operator $T(g)$ on the space $H(\chi)$ by $T(g)f(x) := f(xg)$. One can check that $T : g\mapsto T(g)$ is a unitary representation on $H(\chi)$.

Let $\varphi$ be a continuous function on $G$ of compact support. Then they also define an operator $T_\varphi$, which I assume is an operator on $H(\chi)$, given by
$$T_\varphi := \int\varphi(g)T(g)dg$$
where I assume the integral is over $G$, and for $f\in H(\chi)$, they want
$$(T_\varphi f)(x) := \int_G\varphi(g)f(xg)dg$$
For two continuous compactly supported functions $\varphi_1,\varphi_2$ on $G$, let $\varphi_1*\varphi_2$ denote the convolution. On page 21, they claim:

1. $T_{\varphi_1*\varphi_2} = T_{\varphi_1}T_{\varphi_2}$ (I assume $T_{\varphi_1}T_{\varphi_2}$ denotes composition of operators?)
2. $T_{\varphi^*} = T_\varphi^*$, where $\varphi^*(g) = \overline{\varphi(g^{-1})}$ (presumably the bar denotes complex conjugation?)
3. "$T_{\varphi*\varphi*}$ is a self-adjoint positive definite operator."

I don't understand what they mean by (3). Do they mean $T_{(\varphi *\varphi)^*}$? I'm also having some trouble verifying that (1) and (2) are true. (also I can't check (3), since I don't know what they mean).

My field is normally algebraic geometry, and I haven't worked with integrals for many years now, so perhaps this is all relatively easy, but I would appreciate it greatly if someone could spell out how to check these three properties.

EDIT: Also, given two subspaces $H_1,H_2$ of a hilbert space $H$, what does $H_1\stackrel{.}{+} H_2$ mean?

Comment: Some quick hints that I'll perhaps revisit if I get time: for 1. Fubini's theorem  together with changing variables $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ as needed (which doesn't affect the outcome as you're integrating over $G$ which is preserved by inversion) should do the trick. 2. should be almost immediate once you remember that integrating is a linear functional and pull conjugation out (again, change variables as needed). For 3: yes, this looks like a typo. That it is self-adjoint follows from 2. as adjunction is an involution on operators...

Comment: ..and checking that it's positive-definite should follow again by changing variables $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ and seeing that you're essentially integrating $\varphi\varphi^*\geq 0$.

Comment: They meant $T_{\varphi \ast \varphi^*} = T_\varphi T_\varphi^*$ and $T_{\varphi^* \ast \varphi}=T_\varphi^* T_\varphi$ are self-adjoints (and positive semi-definite). Why don't you take $G = GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\Gamma = SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ (or $GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$ or $GL_2(\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q})$) to make things easier ? See [Garrett](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_2013-14/12_2_transition_Eis.pdf) for an example of real Eisenstein series converted to an automorphic representation $\pi \cong \otimes_p \pi_p$ on $GL_2(\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: They mean $T_{\phi \ast \phi^{\star}}$, the operator corresponding to the function $\phi \ast \phi^{\star}$. By 1 and 2, that will be $T_{\phi} \circ T^{\star}_{\phi}$, where the last $\star$ is the adjoint ( as operator). Now you have to see that for any operator, $T \circ T^{\star}$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: This "applying $T$ to a function" is analogous to passing from a linear representation of a finite group $G$ to a representation of the group algebra $k[G]$.  The operation in the group algebra is convolution. Now you only have to be a bit careful with the analysis, but the algebra is not difficult at this stage